# Sequential Neural Network

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, nnet

I am trying to construct a neural network as a generative model, to predict the next vector following a sequence of vectors (each vector is a distribution of real numbers of length `n`).

My thought was to take `k` previous sequences and concatenate them to have a `k`x`n` input vector. To train the model, I would have the next vector in the sequence as the output. As I am looking for non-deterministic output, I was going to use a sigmoid activation function with low gradient.

Does this procedure seem reasonable?

In the hope it does, I tried implementing it in R using both the `nnet` and `neuralnet` libraries, but it the documentation and examples I came across, it seems the input and output vectors must be of the same length. What is the syntax to train on input/output vectors of varying length in either of those modules?

A sample of my input vector is:

```
      [,1]      
 [1,] 0         
 [2,] 0         
 [3,] 0.6       
 [4,] 0.4       
 [5,] 0         
 [6,] 0         
 [7,] 0.06666667
 [8,] 0.6666667 
 [9,] 0         
[10,] 0.2666667 
[11,] 0         
[12,] 0.4       
[13,] 0         
[14,] 0         
[15,] 0.6
```

And output vector:

```
      [,1]    
 [1,] 0         
 [2,] 0         
 [3,] 0.8571429 
 [4,] 0         
 [5,] 0.1428571
```

N.B. The above sample has `n=5`, `k=3`, although my actual dataset has `n~200`. In both cases, the individual vectors are normalized to 1.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You asking for multi dimensional regression like in the financial ones?

Comment: In a sense, yes. I am looking to generate the next vector having seen (and learnt) from previous vectors. My data isn't financial, but it could also apply there.

Comment: This is essentially a neural network with 15 input variables and 5 output variables, right?

Comment: Assuming it's a good methodology for modeling sequential data, then yes it is!

Comment: Whether or not neural networks are good for sequential data is probably a question for stats exchange and not this site (which is more geared towards programming issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this is very simple and naive approach, which rather won't yield good results. Your are trying to perform the regression from set of time series into time series treating everything as simple attributes and simple model. There have been thousands of papers/research regarding time series predictions, representing time dependence etc.You are facing a hard type of prediction problem here, finding the good solution will require lots of work, and proposed model has a very little chance of working well.

From your text I deduce, that you actually have a sequence of time series, and for the "time window" `[t-k,t-k+1,..,t-1]` you want to predict the value (time series) in `t`. If this is true, then this is actualy time series prediction problem, where each attribute is the time series on its own, and all time series related techniques can be used here, as for example recurrent neural networks (if you really like NNs) or conditional RBMs (if you really want a non-deterministic, generative model - as they have been succesfully applied to time series prediction in recent years).

Now few other doubts:

> As I am looking for non-deterministic output, I was going to use a sigmoid activation function

Sigmoid activation function is not **non-deterministic**. If you are looking for non deterministic models you should think about some architectures like RBMs, but as @Ben Allison mentioned in the comment, traditional neural networks can also be used in the probabilistic fashion with some simple modifications.

> with low gradient.

What do you mean by low gradient? That your activation function has a small slope? This will result in a problematic learning in case of simple training procedures (like BP algorithm)

> [DATA]

Your data looks like you normalized each time series so it sums to `1` which is rather not popular approach to data normzliazation in neural networks (you rather normalize data column-wise, so each dimension is normalized, not each sample).

> Title

Your question, and model is not "sequentional" and does not include "varying vector lengths", looking for papers about such phenomena won't lead you to answer for your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer – I will look into temporal rbms.

Comment: Neural nets can be viewed as probability models if you view the output of the sigmoid function as the parameter to a binomial, or in the multiple outputs case the softmax as parameters to a multinomial. See David Mackay's textbook for further elaboration on this view.

Comment: I did not write that it cannot be used as a probabilistic model by some additional modifications, but you are right, it should be expressed in other words.